# Button actions doesn't work in a Controller

Tags: php, button

First of all this is a "mini" project for a course i have, so please do not guide me towards using a MVC-framework like CakePHP, laravel. We are not allowed to use that for this.
I am still in a beginners phase within PHP, but have 1-2years of Java knowledge.

Problem:

I have 2 buttons, (Send, and Update).
When pressing these buttons, they are supposed to do some actions of course, in my case, Send => should send a message to my SQL server, Update => should get the sql table and show it on the screen.

I have no problems of the first step if you can call it that for this web-application, which is choosing a name and accessing the main-room where the messages is viewed.

Why doesn't it work?

Would really appreciate some help from you guys.

The rest of the code:
https://github.com/jabbeboy/1dv608writerswall

Code snippet of my controller:

```
public function handle() {
    if ($this->wall->wantsToUpdate()) {
        $list = $this->useModel->doUpdate();
        $this->wall->setChatMsgList($list);
    }
    if ($this->wall->wantsToSend()) {
        $msg = $this->wall->getMessageModel();
        $this->useModel->doSend($msg);
    }
}
```

This is how the buttons are configured in my View:

```
private static $sendButton = "WallView::Submit";
private static $updateButton = "WallView::Update";

<input type="submit" id='.self::$sendButton.' name='.self::$sendButton.'
value="Send" />

public function wantsToSend() {
    return isset($_POST[self::$sendButton]);
}
```

Comment: Your view is hard to read. It contains PHP and HTML without the use of opening and closing brackets for PHP. As you posted it, you would get errors.

Comment: Oh, this is just snippets from the code.

Comment: Where is your form for the button?

Comment: I guess it's too big to post the whole form here in the comments. 
So here is the exact link. It starts on row 38.

[link](https://github.com/jabbeboy/1dv608writerswall/blob/master/writers-wall/view/WallView.php)